# CSS Flexbox first vertical list then start multiple columns once vertical space runs out

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to set flexbox to first use vertical space then start multiple columns once vertical space runs out. If there still isn't enough space, then use vertical scroll.

```
#box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: calc(100% - 200px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 100px);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
.item {
  background: gray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

My issue is that this will scroll horizontally instead of vertically.

Comment: Could you add a visual sketch or image of what you are trying to achieve? I cannot graps like what you need.

Comment: What horizontal scroll? https://jsfiddle.net/3woyd8f5/

Comment: You should be able to do that by moving the `overflow:auto` declaration to a new wrapper element. However, if the order of the items is important, that seems bad for usability. For those who are having trouble understanding the question, you need enough "item" elements to both wrap and trigger overflow to see the issue.